# ondrag event only fires when text is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I noticed that drag events, ondrag, ondragstart etc only fire when text is selected.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="draggable" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#999;">
    <div>test</div>
</div>
```

... and this javascript:

```
$("#draggable").on("drag", function(){ console.info("dragged")});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ2pf/10/

If you try dragging, nothing fires, but once you selected the text it will fire. I can always replicate dragging with mouse events but drag works cross iframes, I can also replicate that but that would make the code really unclean.

My question is, does anyone know how to make drag events fire without the need to select the text?

Comment: That's what I'd expect to happen for a non-draggable element...

Comment: What Ivan is saying (since I didn't get it at first either) is that in order for a 'drag' event to be triggered, the element has to be draggable to begin with. The div itself is not inherently draggable. Selected text is. I'm now curious about how the text is triggering the event... is it due to the event bubbling up to the next element?

Comment: It is possible to disable text selection with `-webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none` or something like that…

Answer (score 1):

@Ivan Thanks, you just pointed me to the right direction, I din't know the existence of the draggable attribute.

All it needed was the draggable attribute on the div.

```
<div draggable="true">drag this</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery UI you can active drag&drop events for all DOM elements:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

If you want to active drag for the entire div; you must active it :-)

I make a little fiddle activating drag in the first div 
http://jsfiddle.net/JdVv5/
and one activating it for the "text div"
http://jsfiddle.net/JdVv5/2/

Comment: The point is to use the drag events, not making it draggable.